# Enabling logging in Spring

Tags: java, spring, log4j

We are using RAD 7.5 as IDE and also log4j for logging purpose. we want to enable spring logging.

I tried the following

- Added `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` as a listener in `web.xml`. It is  added before `ContextLoaderListener`.
- `log4j.properties` is present in application war under `WEB-INF`.
- Add the following context parameter in `web.xml`:

---

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

In log 4j added the following

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ALL
```

Even then I am not able to see any output in console or in log file.

Can anyone please let me know the exact steps for enabling spring logging.

Comment: did you try `log4j.logger.org.springframework=TRACE` and have you assigned proper appenders to your logger?

Comment: what is/was your log4j version?

Answer (score 17):

In your properties file you should have

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL
```

not

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ALL
```

See [this section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826) in the Spring reference.

Comment: I have log4j dependency 1.2.17 and it works both with `log4j.logger.org.springframework=ALL` and `log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL`. https://goo.gl/yLwW2b (Logger hierarchy) states that Category was replaced by Logger: `However, since log4j version 1.2, Logger class has replaced the Category class.`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using log4j2 using the common XML configuration format, add a Logger in your Loggers node:

```
<Logger name="org.springframework" level="trace"/>
```

Normally, the appenders used will be the ones attached to the Root entry.