# Why is my request hitting two controllers?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class TypoWorkflowController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/workflow/typo-workflow/moreInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String serveMoreInfo(@RequestParam(value = "taskId", required=false) String taskId, ModelMap modelMap) {
        return "typo-workflow-more-info";
    }
}
```

My tiles-def file contains:

```
<definition name="typo-workflow-more-info" template="/WEB_INF/jsp/workflow/typo-workflow/moreInfo.jsp"/>
```

My JSP is plain old HTML.

When I hit the url `/workflow/typo-workflow/moreInfo`, Tomcat throws a `StackOverflowError`.

When I step through in debug mode, I see that I'm hitting my controller first, as I would expect, but then I hit another controller, at the method:

```
@Controller
@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ContentServingController {

/* ... */
    @RequestMapping({"/*", "/**/*"})
    public ModelAndView serveContent(HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

As I poked around, it *seeeeeeemed* like we were in there to respond to a request for `/WEB_INF/jsp/workflow/typo-workflow/moreInfo.jsp`, but this doesn't happen for other controllers that operate in the same way (returning a View name).

So, can anyone provide me with some pointers for debugging this. Why would I be hitting a controller for a JSP anyway? Isn't a JSP supposed to be a little servlet itself?

Comment: Do you have in your HTML any references which might cause a second request for the other controller? During Debugging you did check that the same thread is calling your controllers.

Comment: Looking in the log may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468999/enabling-logging-in-spring Also what is the purpose of ContentServingController. Maybe there is a better way to implement what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tiles def is pointing to the WEB_INF folder when it should be pointing to the WEB-INF folder (dash instead of underscore) so spring doesn't know where to look within the app and is just making a normal http request, which is getting caught by the wildcard match.